# completion callback from HealthKit query

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, completion

I am trying to determine when a query has finished executing. I have implemented a completion callback however, as it is called with each loop I would have to devise some scheme to determine when the query has actually completed. Is there another way?

I am hesitant to block the main thread while the query is executing.

```
    func updateData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> () ) {
        .....
        statsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate as Date)  { [unowned self] statistics, stop in
            if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let date = statistics.startDate
                        let value = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                        self.setCount(value, forDate: date)
                        completion(true)
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        healthStore.execute(query)
    |
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `query`? You can specify a `completionHandler` in its `init`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksourcequery/1614367-init

Comment: Hello Paolo,, Thank you for your comment. I awn using HKStatisticsCollectionQuery which does not appear to allow a completionHandler:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery

Comment: I ended up adding a condition - in this case if the enddate is greater than today - then call completion

                        if( statistics.endDate > endDate ){
                            completion(true)
                        }